# How to make Mutationobserver console.log() my changes only one time

Tags: javascript, angular, mutation-observers

for example:

```
<div id="someId">
  <h1>someText</h1>
</div>
```

## someText

=>> someText keeps changing over time

```
let observer = new MutationObserver((mutations,observer)=>{

 mutations.forEach(muta=>{
 console.log((muta.target as Element).innerHTML)
})
})
```

```
 const config = {childList: true};
let div = document.getElementById('someId');
observer.observe((div  as Node), config);
```

how to make it so that the text is displayed once and at the same time do not turn off the observer

I tried to do like this:

```
let observer = new MutationObserver((mutations,observer)=>{

 mutations.forEach(muta=>{
 console.log((muta.target as Element).innerHTML)
observer.disconnect() 
})
})
```

but I don't want to shutdown the Observer so that when new changes arrive, print them to the console again only once

Comment: What do you mean? I just checked and the change is logged only once. What is changing the content? It's probably doing it multiple times. You might want to inspect "muta" element and react only on certain type of update

Comment: Add a variable outside the callback e.g. `printed`, check it inside the callback and only print if (!printed), then set it to true.